# How can I pass on an on click event to a component via props?

Tags: reactjs

I have a floating action button that I want to use to enable night mode but I have gotten stuck on how to pass the on the click event so that the mode actives. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong can someone give me some guidance?

I was trying to follow this guide. https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-add-dark-mode-to-a-react-application/
So far

```
class FloatingActionButton extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
    
        super(props);
const [theme, setTheme] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light'
  );
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    if (theme === 'light') {
      setTheme('dark');
    } else {
      setTheme('light');
    }
  };

   }
   useEffect(() => {
     localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
     document.body.className = theme;
   }, [theme]);

config({
        
            floatingActionButtonConfig: {
                icon: 'runner',
                closeIcon: 'icon ion-md-close',
                position: {
                    my: 'right bottom',
                    at: 'right bottom',
                    offset: '-16 -16'
                }
         
  
         
            }
        });

        
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <div id="app-container" className={`App ${theme}`}>

                <SpeedDialAction
                    hint="Increase Font"
                    icon="growfont"
                    onClick={() =>
                        alert("Increase Font Clicked!!")
                    }
                />
                <SpeedDialAction
                    hint="turn on night mode"
                    icon="night mode"
                    onClick={() => toggleTheme}
                />
      
        );
    }
}


export default FloatingActionButton;
```

tried to pass in the toggle theme into the on click listener and reference it in the function  earlier in the code but it is not working properly, any guidance on how to improve will be appreicated. I am geting a theme and toggle not defined but I am unsure why as they are being  initalized properly.

Would using context be better?

After updating the code  to what was provided to me below minus the effect the page loads properly but I am unable to get on click to engage darkmode

I added this to the button and found no change

```
           <SpeedDialAction
                  hint="turn on night mode"
                  icon="night mode"
                  onClick={() => this.toggleTheme(
(this.state.theme == 'dark')
                  )}
              />
```

Comment: Please remember to properly format your code, including indentation. That said, it looks like you're mixing the methodologies for full blown components, and functional component functions. Better to pick one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` can only be used in a functional component. If you are going to use a class component, you need to assign to `this.state` in the constructor, and `this.setState` to update the state. Your code should look something like this:

```
class FloatingActionButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            theme: localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light'
        };
        config({
            floatingActionButtonConfig: {
                icon: 'runner',
                closeIcon: 'icon ion-md-close',
                position: {
                    my: 'right bottom',
                    at: 'right bottom',
                    offset: '-16 -16'
                }
            }
        });
    }
    toggleTheme(){
        if(this.state.theme == 'light'){
           this.setState({theme: 'dark'});
        } else {
           this.setState({theme: 'light'});
        }
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <div id="app-container" className={`App ${this.state.theme}`}>

                <SpeedDialAction
                    hint="Increase Font"
                    icon="growfont"
                    onClick={() =>
                        alert("Increase Font Clicked!!")
                    }
                />
                <SpeedDialAction
                    hint="turn on night mode"
                    icon="night mode"
                    onClick={() => this.toggleTheme()}
                />
      
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code to what you  provided and now I can get the page to load properly but the theme is not toggling dark mode.

Comment: I tested it and it works. Is there anything else in your code that could be causing this? Try logging out the theme (`console.log(this.state.theme);`) to see if it is changing on click.

Comment: I forgot to add a piece of code but I have added it to the original question but could it be related to the "use effect" being missing?  I forgot to add that part to my original question

Comment: the original tutorial had ```   useEffect(() => {
    document.body.className = theme;
  }, [theme]) ```  after  the toggle theme could that be why it is not working?

Comment: If you have it set up as a class component, using hooks won't work. you need to use the lifecycle methods (`componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, etc)